# Outlook web add-in - Folders created through EWS calls not showing up in OWA. Working fine in Outlook Windows. Could it be my code's issue?

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, add-in, outlook-web-app

I have a Client Project relationship in my web-app. I want to allow my web-app users to be able to file emails right from within Outlook. So in my Outlook Web Add-In, I want to create the client project folders on the fly, if they do not exist already, and move the selected email item in the respective project folder.

My code works fine in Outlook Windows. In Outlook Web, it executes without any errors, but the folders are not displayed. If I reload the web page, the folders are there and the email is in the right folder.

I have talked to Microsoft support and they are saying that OWA is working fine.

Can anybody help me spot any issues with my code?

CreateFolderPath EWS operation is not allowed in my add-in. So that does not seem to be an option.

The manifest file is available at https://newdev.timesolv.com/Integrations/addin/SimpleVersion.xml

Comment: So the folders are just not visible on a particular platform, or they are just not there at all? What is your EWS code?

Comment: Yes, the folders are just not visible in OWA. If I reload the web page, they are there. I am using CreateFolder EWS. Please see https://newdev.timesolv.com/Integrations/javascript/AddIn.js

Comment: So the problem is OWA does not refresh after you create the folder.

Comment: Yes. But as there are two versions of the OWA. The new one does not refresh at all whereas the old one refreshes such that only one folder is visible. If you had created a folder B inside folder A, folder B is not visible.

Comment: That sure sounds like a bug in OWA. Is opening a support case with MS an option?

Comment: I have logged it as a bug with Microsoft. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/683

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. It has been [submitted to Microsoft](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/683) and they have acknowledged it.

**Update**: On January 27th, 2020, the issue was closed by OfficeDev. I confirmed and it was working fine.